# Why does my PHP reCAPTCHA only display on Chrome and Safari?

Tags: php, html, cross-browser, recaptcha

I'm using the PHP reCAPTCHA on my company's website. I basically just followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php which is pretty straightforward. Anyway, everything displays and submits fine on Chrome and Safari, but on IE10 and Firefox the reCAPTCHA box simply doesn't show up client-side. I somewhat diverge from the tutorial in the way that I don't have a separate verification page, but I still don't see how this would affect the image displaying on various browsers. Any suggestions?

```
<?php
    $page = "visit";
    include 'layout/topnav.php';  
?> 

<script language="JavaScript">
function formValidate() {
    if (document.data.Comments.value == "") { alert("Please include a quick question"); return false; }
    else if (document.data.Email.value == "") { alert("Please include your email."); return false; }
    else return true;
}
</script>

<?php
$Added = False;
if (isset($_POST['submit1'])){

  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "xxxxx";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                            $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                            $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
   // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly

    echo "Your CAPTCHA response was not accepted. Please try again. See the Help button to the right of the entry field to learn more.";
    $Email=$_POST['Email'];
    $Comments=$_POST['Comments'];
    $Added = False;
  } 

  else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification

    /* Add to Database */

    $Email = '';
    $Comments = '';
    $Added = True;
   }

  }

  if(!$Added)
  {
  ?>


<html>
<head>
<body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
<form method="post" action="quick_question.php" name="data" onsubmit="return formValidate()">     
<b>Your Quick Question:<font color="red">*</font></b><br />
        <textarea wrap="hard" name="Comments" rows="5" cols="55" id="question" class="inputBox" ><? echo $Comments?></textarea>

        <table cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
                <td width="40%" valign="top"><b>Your E-mail:<font color="red">*</font></b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="Email" size="10" id="email" class="inputBox" value="<? echo $Email?>"/></td>
            </tr>

        <tr><td>
        <b>CAPTCHA Verification:</b><font color="red">*</font>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
        <?php
            require_once('recaptchalib.php');
            $publickey = "yyyy"; // you got this from the signup page
            echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td id="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit1" />
        </td></tr>

        </table>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Chrome likes to auto correct bad HTML syntax. Make sure your recaptcha_get_html() function returns proper HTML code. What is the recaptcha_get_html function?

Does the source code contain any reCaptcha stuff, or is it entirely missing?

Do you have an example of the web page somewhere live?

Sorry this is marked as an answer, I can not comment on posts still?

Comment: Here's a link to the page: http://dept.ku.edu/~wstaff/question/quick_question.php I'm assuming I'm just using bad HTML syntax at some point that's just throwing it off, thanks for the insight. I basically posted the page's source above; I know the reCAPTCHA tutorial states that the body tag is necessary or it won't render on certain browsers, so maybe this is the cause.

Comment: Odd, but now the CAPTCHA image is rendering on all four web browsers. I did absolutely no changes over the weekend...

Comment: If anyone else reads this post, I think the issue wasn't in the browser itself but the code being blocked by Google based on the unusual amount of traffic it was receiving. I tested my site in Chrome, Firefox, IE, and Safari on my personal laptop and the captcha displays fine, whereas my normal work computer where I've been testing still doesn't display on Chrome, IE, and Firefox (only display in Safari still). I'd imagine that's why all four web browsers rendered fine after a weekend away, but started to block access after a day or two of testing.