# Why does reCAPTCHA only show up on certain computers/browsers?

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

I added the PHP reCAPTCHA to my employer's quick question form, here's a link to it: https://dept.ku.edu/~wstaff/question/quick_question.php

For some reason, the CAPTCHA box itself won't show up when I go to it on my work computer. This happens in Firefox, IE10, and Chrome. However, it shows up fine in Safari. I work in a library on my university's campus and when I go to the same site on a library computer, the CAPTCHA loads fine on every web browser. Could this be some sort of spam prevention due to my testing the CAPTCHA too much on my work computer?

I had this problem in the past: [Why does my PHP reCAPTCHA only display on Chrome and Safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335705/why-does-my-php-recaptcha-only-display-on-chrome-and-safari) but out of nowhere the CAPTCHA started rendering again on my computer so I stopped worrying about it (dumb mistake).

The really weird thing here is I just tried to load the page on my coworker's computer and no CAPTCHA shows up! Something to do with the network being blocked? Why would only Safari work?

Has anyone else had this issue with reCAPTCHA? I was recommended in my previous post that it could be bad HTML syntax causing the rendering issue, and I'm in the process of cleaning up my syntax, but it doesn't make sense why all of the browsers on another computer would render the CAPTCHA fine whereas mine leaves it completely blank, i.e. the box doesn't show up at all.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious and for my beginner-level HTML/PHP knowledge. Also, thanks in advance for any guidance.

Forgot to mention, I've implemented reCAPTCHA on various other forms on my employer's website, all of which still display without issues.

Comment: My guess is your company firewall is blocking the Javascript.

Comment: Wouldn't the <noscript> tags that reCAPTCHA implements bypass this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the following, maybe you spot the reason:

- disable any advertisment blocking extensions, if any
- open Firefox's web console (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console) to see if there are Javascript errors
- compare the network activity of Network Monitor in Firefox https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor on a machine what has the reCAPTCHA and on one, where it does not appear. There might be some missing or failed requests.

Comment: Thanks for the Firefox web console recommendation. Apparently Firefox, IE, and Chrome block "active mixed content" by default on newer versions. My computer is running Firefox 30, whereas the library computers are running Firefox 21 so the blocking hadn't been implemented yet. Here's a link explaining how to fix a website blocking mixed content: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent/How_to_fix_website_with_mixed_content

Comment: Also, here's a link to a direct fix to my problem!! http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/google-tools/blocked-loading-mixed-active-content